# AEM 6.3 Screens - clientlibs not getting referred on device in a custom component in a sequence channel

Tags: aem

Css and js render on a device when written inside the markup, but not render when on device when they are referred as clientlibs. The custom component contains a simple div and simple css and jQuery function . When the same css and js is used within the html markup as  and  tag, the css and js work on a device , but when being referred as clientlibs, they do not render on device. The css and js work fine on both edit and preview mode of channel

This is the way I am referring the clientlibs -

```
 <sly data-sly-use.clientLib="/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html" data-sly-call="${clientLib.all @ categories='screen.test'}" data-sly-unwrap/>

<div class ="testclass">This is test text.</div>
```

The channel renders with a simple text without any css and js applied. This is how it work when css and js is included in markup -

```
<div class ="testclass">This is a test text</div>

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".testclass").animate({left: '371px'});

    });

<style>
.testclass{
background:#98bf21;
height:100px;
width:100px;
position:absolute;
    }
</style>
```

I even checked the we.retail screen demo provided, it is also referring the css and js in the same sightly way of referring clientlibs, the css and js does render fine on their application channel, and they have not used any custom component in the sequence channel.

Is there any extra configuration required to make the clientlibs referable on a deivce in AEM screens ? Please let me know , I am blocked because of this..

REPLY

Comment: Have you configured the clientlibs references, and categories correctly? Templates must refer to client libs path and client libs should be referred by the correct categories. I think one of these are missing if you can see these includes rendered in the output.

Comment: Try requesting the page with the query parameter `debugClientLibs=true`, it will allow you to see individual CSS and JS files being loaded. Perhaps you missed something in `js.txt` or `css.txt`. Another possible reason is that the clientlib may be cached.

When you access the page using your device, do you hit the author or the publish instance? If it's the latter, perhaps the clientlib is not installed on the publish.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, the clientlibs load fine in on a desktop browser, I am referring to accessing the clientlibs on the aem screens android player on a device and not on a browser in a device https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/administer/screens.html